# PHP PDO HY093 error on SELECT COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Been researching all the similar Q&A around, but i can't seem to find a solution, after banging my head on the walls for over 2 days now.

I'm building a query based on user input, so i'm not going to post all the mumbo jumbo.

Consider `$binds` an associative array of this type `:key => val` for binding values once the query is complete and prepared.

This is part of a class function (showing only the part after the query is built):

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($stmt);
foreach($binds as $k => $v){
    $col = explode('.',substr($k,1));//because all keys start with ':' and some end with '.key'
    $col = $col[0];
    if($col == 'year'){
        $col = 'model_year';
    }
    $stmt->bindValue($k,$v,$this->tblInfo->pdo_param($col));//tblInfo is a class
    //holding an array with column names and types for the table i'm working with
    //and a function that returns PDO::PARAM_ type based on the column type
}
if($stmt->execute()){
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
return array('binds' => $binds,$stmt,'err' => $stmt->errorInfo(),'result' => $res);
```

This is a `json_encoded` output of the function:

```
{
"binds": {
    ":make": "audi",
    ":model": "a4",
    ":year.1": "2013",
    ":price.1": "9990",
    ":gearbox.0": "auto",
    ":fuel.0": "diesel",
    ":mileage.0": "0",
    ":mileage.1": "350000"
},
"0": {
    "queryString": "SELECT COUNT(active) AS main FROM ads_auto WHERE active=true
 AND has_photo=true AND make=:make AND model=:model AND model_year <= :year.1 AND
price <= :price.1 AND gearbox=:gearbox.0 AND fuel=:fuel.0 AND mileage BETWEEN 
:mileage.0 AND :mileage.1"
},
"err": [
    "HY093",
    null,
    null
],
"result": null
}
```

AND `debugDumpParams()`:

```
SQL: [245] SELECT COUNT(active) AS main FROM ads_auto WHERE active=true AND
has_photo=true AND make=:make AND model=:model AND model_year <= :year.1 AND 
price <= :price.1 AND gearbox=:gearbox.0 AND fuel=:fuel.0 AND mileage BETWEEN
:mileage.0 AND :mileage.1

Params:  8
Key: Name: [5]  :make      paramno=-1 name=[5]  ":make"      is_param=1 param_type=2
Key: Name: [6]  :model     paramno=-1 name=[6]  ":model"     is_param=1 param_type=2
Key: Name: [7]  :year.1    paramno=-1 name=[7]  ":year.1"    is_param=1 param_type=1
Key: Name: [8]  :price.1   paramno=-1 name=[8]  ":price.1"   is_param=1 param_type=1
Key: Name: [10] :gearbox.0 paramno=-1 name=[10] ":gearbox.0" is_param=1 param_type=2
Key: Name: [7]  :fuel.0    paramno=-1 name=[7]  ":fuel.0"    is_param=1 param_type=2
Key: Name: [10] :mileage.0 paramno=-1 name=[10] ":mileage.0" is_param=1 param_type=1
Key: Name: [10] :mileage.1 paramno=-1 name=[10] ":mileage.1" is_param=1 param_type=1
```

Obviously `$stmt->execute()` evals to `FALSE` so its not fetching.

`$binds` array contains exactly what `$stmt` needs to bind.

I'm not using any quotes.

I read about issues with COUNT() and PDO, so i tried a `SELECT id` instead of `SELECT COUNT`, but it makes no difference since `$stmt->execute()` is `FALSE`.

**WHY OH WHY** am i getting HY093? What am i missing?

Using PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB.

Comment: Is `:fuel.0` a valid placeholder name? I've never seen those before.

Comment: Well, (fuel,price,gearbox) and other params can come in from users end, as: a string, a one value array, or a multiple value array. So for when it is an array, i add the array key to the placeholder name. I honestly don't know if adding .1 or .0 to the placeholder name is ok. I changed that to _0 or _1, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @tadman's suggestion, i dug into PDO's source, and it seems the problem WAS INDEED the placeholder name.

According to Parser source code:

BINDCHR     = [:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+;

Placeholder name can be alphanumeric + underscore, so adding '.' (dot) is a no no.

Thanks for the pointer. All is OK now.